# How to automatically select corresponding grid rows in Jqxgrid spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, jqxgrid

[The demo of spreadsheet](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/spreadsheet.htm?light) is awesome, looks like it is as strong as excel.:)

Two questions for spreadsheet,

1) How to automatically select corresponding grid rows in spreadsheet? when user click on first grid cell of the first pinned column by mouse,meantime the left mouse is not up ,move mouse to next grid cell of the first pinned column constantly.

suppose user moves the first grid cell to third grid cell, the corresponding 3 grid rows will be automatically selected.

suppose user moves the first grid cell to fifth grid cell, the corresponding 5 grid rows will be automatically selected. some thing like that.

2) According to the the spreadsheet demo, when user keeps on moving mouse to the 12th grid cell of pinned column, How to make the vertical scroll bar automatically to scroll down so that the the 13th,14th,15th,16th,17th…. grid row will show up?, so that user continue moving to next grid cell of the pinned column constantly.

Thanks a lot for you guys great help.

Best Regards